# Are simple where clauses executed before wildcard LIKE clauses?

Tags: mysql

Fairly simple one here (I hope).

I would like to know if MySQL is smart enough to optimise / run simple `WHERE` clauses before wildcard clauses that cannot use indexes e.g. `WHERE LIKE '%abc%'`

As an example, consider the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `organization_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `users_name_index` (`name`),
  KEY `users_organization_id_foreign` (`organization_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `users_organization_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`organization_id`) REFERENCES `organizations` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

And consider the following query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `users` 
WHERE `organization_id` = 1
AND `name` LIKE '%abc%'
```

I know that MySQL cannot use the index on `name` because of the wildcard prefix. However, MySQL can use the foreign key `organization_id` to filter the results.

So, the question is, will MySQL be smart enough to fetch the users with an `organization_id` of `1`, and then execute a wildcard lookup on that resulting dataset? Or, is the inverse true (MySQL will first perform the wildcard search, and then limit those results to records with an `organization_id` of `1`?

**UPDATE**

Here is the result of the `EXPLAIN` plan:

[image]

Comment: For your specific example, the best thing to do would be to [check the execution plan](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html) and find out if the query is using the index on `origanisation_id`. As a general rule though it depends. While it may be efficient to use the index on `organisation_id`, the cost of doing a bookmark lookup to then get the other columns may exceed the cost of just doing a clustered index scan in the first place. This will vary depending on the exact scenario

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `users` 
WHERE `organization_id` = 1
AND `name` LIKE '%abc%'
`

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I've added the EXPLAIN result as a screenshot.

Comment: From [a brief test](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d742912d305e61e8d3568d430940bcf0) it appears that MySQL is "smart enough" to use the index, but not smart enough to ignore it when it should. In the linked example the query searching for organisation ID 1 is actually 10 times faster before the index is created compared to after it, yet MySQL still uses it if it exists. Doesn't really answer your question, but worth noting that just because an index exists, doesn't necessarily mean it should be used, even if it is part of the where clause.

Comment: I am not that familiar with MySQL though, I know a lot more about SQL Server, and with a [similar example on SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e391b007910fceaa6ac3cb2f19731b28) the index is only used when there are only a handful of rows returned by the index. Even with as few as 10 rows it still opts for a full table scan rather than use the index to filter, then have to look up the main table data anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @GarethD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL (and really any database) will use the index to fetch the rows and then process additional `where` conditions (that are `and`ed in).

If there were no index on `organization_id`, then you don't know which is performed first.  Many databases attempt to optimize where conditions based on the complexity of the comparison, but that is based on internal metrics and might not apply in all cases.

Comment: Good to know... I figured that was likely to be the case given that it makes sense from an optimization perspective. As per the EXPLAIN screenshot I've added, it would appear it is using the index. I just didn't know if it was using the index before or after the wildcard search.